# Getting an assertion error while views testing using invalid data in django

Tags: python, django

I am testing my webapp by developing testcases using invalid data. Everything runs fine except for an assertion error that is bugging me a lot. I am trying to prevent a suer from registering if a same email id like his exists. In such a case, the same form will be rendered with the context as errors.(Check the code written below). But it keeps on showing an assertion error.
Here is my code:

Here is my **views.py**:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            ob = CustomUserCreationForm.register(user_form)
            if ob.is_active is False and ob.is_staff is False:
                return render(request, 'todoapp/waiting.html')
            else:
                return render(request, 'todoapp/admin_success.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'todoapp/register.html', {'errors': user_form.errors})
    return render(request, 'todoapp/register.html', {'form': CustomUserCreationForm()})
```

Here is my **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^register/', views.register, name='register'),
```

Here is my **tests.py**:

```
sent_data = {
            'first_name': 'john',
            'last_name': 'doe',
            'email': 'johndoe@gmail.com',
            'password': 'johndoe'
        }
        response = self.client.post(url, sent_data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        expected_data = {
            'email': 'User with this Email already exists.'
        }
        self.assertEqual(response.context['errors'], expected_data)
```

Here is the **error**:

```
self.assertEqual(response.context['errors'], expected_data)
AssertionError: {'email': [u'User with this Email already exists.']} != {u'errors': {u'email': u'User with this Email already exists.'}}
```

Comment: @khelwood naa its still not working.

Comment: In the assertion error, one of the dicts contains a string mapped to a list. The other contains string mapped to a dict. Neither of them matches the `expected_data` dict in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Assertion Error are because of `left!=right` here you want to compare the message as response you can check for this specific case

```
self.assertEqual(response.context['errors']['email'][0], expected_data['email'])
```

or

better you can modify your expected_data as errors comes in a list

```
expected_data = {
            'email': [u'User with this Email already exists.']
        }

self.assertEqual(response.context['errors'], expected_data)
```

Key is you see what response is actually getting returned and build your expected-data like that now onward.